# Camel SSH multiple session not getting closed after execution

Tags: java, spring, ssh, apache-camel

we have camel route that is having an SSH endpoint and the context containing these routes keep running for a day,before being stopped for next day's run.

Now, we are observing that all these SSH connections that were created are getting closed only when our services is brought down. We make atleast 4 ssh connections in an hour to the same server, so approximately about 96 connections are kept open at the remote server and this is causing issues at the server.

Is there a way to specify to close/terminate the SSH session immediately after execution? (in camel spring xml configurations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked code of camel-ssh, it doesn't call the close method of session close when it finished the execution. 
So I filled a JIRA [CAMEL-7277](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7277) and submitted a patch for it.

Comment: The patch was applied into camel trunk, camel-2.12.x and camel-2.11.x branches. Please checkout the latest snapshot for verification.