# Repository for Camel ssh version 2.11.5?

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I was looking for Camel SSH version 2.11.5. But it seems like maven repository does not have this version. Is these any other repository which I can link to my maven pom?

Basically I was looking for patch which was applied for this issue - 
[Camel SSH multiple session not getting closed after execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229687/camel-ssh-multiple-session-not-getting-closed-after-execution/22240675#22240675?s=2e6867e9df0a4d64aaeeb778b62d0ba3)

Answer (score 1):

Camel 2.11.5 has not been released yet. Also, it does not say in JIRA what is the expected release date: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL/fixforversion/12326258/

So, probably if you want the fix you will need to build a SNAPSHOT version yourself.

**EDIT**: Based on Claus's comment, it will not be released.

Comment: Camel 2.11 is EOL so there will not be a new release.